# how do I return a specific value from event from addevent listner

Tags: javascript, dom, events, listener

I want to return value of "event.target.innerText" from pC to playerChoice and then use it.

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const playerChoice = buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", event => {
        const pC = (event.target.innerText).toLowerCase();
        return (pC);
    });
});
```

i tried this where i am passing the value into function and it worked but i just want to expand my knowledge so just looking for some extra approach

Comment: You can't return a value from addEventListener. You can only add callback code to run when it fires.

Comment: You've got the logic wrong: functions bound to event listeners can't fit in a direct procedural chain.